# Array Helper: Iterate through an array with no known end or beginning

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array containing `line segment` objects.  I am trying to see if a line segment that I selected is connected to another chain of other line segments - whether it's the beginning, middle, or end of a long chain.  What would be the fastest / least expensive way to go through toward the end or beginning (assuming the line segment selected is not the end or the beginning?)

Update - Comments section wanted more context...

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let mouseX = e.offsetX,
        mouseY = e.offsetY;
      if (self.mode.isPencilMode && self.mouseIsDown) {
        // create the line and add to the list
        var x0 = self.pos[0],
          y0 = self.pos[1];
        var line = new Line Object;
        self.lines.push(line);
        self.pos = [mouseX, mouseY];
      }
      self.render();
    });
```

Thus, `self.lines` is an array that contains the new `Line` objects that are created.  I need to see if these are connected and when a user selects them, then the `chain` of line segments until the beginning or end is selected...

Comment: do you have an example of this kind of array? it looks more like a double chained list.

Comment: @NinaScholz It's in canvas - essentially the code is written to where `Line` objects are added to an array on mouse listener events.  Within a select mode, one of these `Line` objects will be selected.  Thus, I need to see if that line is connected to others

Answer (score 0):

I would take an own form of a linked list where all nodes (in your case lines) have all information to the connected nodes/lines.

Then you could store three points as meta information to this kind of linked list with a pointer to **start**, **end** and the **actual node**.

With this information, you could add nodes to start and end to the actual node.